# A cfhttp "POST" in php

Tags: php, coldfusion, httprequest

I have a ColdFusion page that appends the a URL with form variables.  I'm trying replicate this code in php:

```
 <cfhttp method="Post" url='http://api.test.com/import-lead-data.php'>
            <cfoutput>
                <cfhttpparam name="BAL_ONE" type="formField" value="#BAL_ONE#">
         <!---  <cfhttpparam name="MTG_ONE_INT" type="formField" value="#MTG_ONE_INT#">
                <cfhttpparam name="MTG_TWO" type="formField" value="#MTG_TWO#">
                <cfhttpparam name="BAL_TWO" type="formField" value="#BAL_TWO#">
                <cfhttpparam name="ADD_CASH" type="formField" value="#ADD_CASH#">--->
                <cfhttpparam name="PRODUCT" type="formField" value="#PRODUCT#">
                <cfhttpparam name="PROP_ST" type="formField" value="#PROP_ST#">
                <cfhttpparam name="CRED_GRADE" type="formField" value="#CRED_GRADE#">
                <cfhttpparam name="PROP_ZIP" type="formField" value="#PROP_ZIP#">
                <cfhttpparam name="PROP_DESC" type="formField" value="#PROP_DESC#">
                <cfhttpparam name="SPEC_HOME" type="formField" value="#SPEC_HOME#">
                <cfhttpparam name="PURCHASE_CONTRACT" type="formField" value="#PURCHASE_CONTRACT#">
                <cfhttpparam name="EST_VAL" type="formField" value="#EST_VAL#">
                <cfhttpparam name="DOWN_PMT" type="formField" value="#DOWN_PMT#">
                <cfhttpparam name="LOAN_TYPE" type="formField" value="#LOAN_TYPE#">
                <cfhttpparam name="BUY_TIMEFRAME" type="formField" value="#BUY_TIMEFRAME#">
                <cfhttpparam name="AGENT_FOUND" type="formField" value="#AGENT_FOUND#">
                <cfhttpparam name="VA_STATUS" type="formField" value="#VA_STATUS#">
                <cfhttpparam name="INCOME" type="formField" value="#INCOME#">
                <cfhttpparam name="ANNUAL_VERIFIABLE_INCOME" type="formField" value="#ANNUAL_VERIFIABLE_INCOME#">
                <cfhttpparam name="FHA_BANK_FORECLOSURE" type="formField" value="#FHA_BANK_FORECLOSURE#">
                <cfhttpparam name="NUM_MORTGAGE_LATES" type="formField" value="#NUM_MORTGAGE_LATES#">
                <cfhttpparam name="EMAIL" type="formField" value="#EMAIL#">
                <cfhttpparam name="FNAME" type="formField" value="#FNAME#">
                <cfhttpparam name="LNAME" type="formField" value="#LNAME#">
                <cfhttpparam name="ADDRESS" type="formField" value="#ADDRESS#">
                <cfhttpparam name="CITY" type="formField" value="#CITY#">
                <cfhttpparam name="STATE" type="formField" value="#STATE#">
                <cfhttpparam name="ZIP" type="formField" value="#ZIP#">
                <cfhttpparam name="PRI_PHON" type="formField" value="#PRI_PHON#">
                <cfhttpparam name="SEC_PHON" type="formField" value="#SEC_PHON#">
                <cfhttpparam name="CAPTURE_METHOD" type="formField" value="#CAPTURE_METHOD#">
                <cfhttpparam name="AID" type="formField" value="#AID#">
                <cfhttpparam name="SRLP" type="formField" value="#SRLP#">
                <cfhttpparam name="SCid" type="formField" value="#SCid#">
                <cfhttpparam name="BUYER_ID" type="formField" value="#BUYER_ID#">
                <cfhttpparam name="CID" type="formField" value="#CID#">
                <cfhttpparam name="PPCID" type="formField" value="#session.PPCID#">
            </cfoutput>
        </cfhttp>
```

I assume I would use a httpRquest (meth: post)?  But I'm not sure.

Comment: This block of code does not do what you describe. You said "have a ColdFusion page that appends the a URL with form variables", but this block does not do that. This block makes an HTTP POST request with nothing but form fields. It does nothing with URL variables.

Comment: Sorry, this cfhttp POSTS the form variables to the URL specified.  I want to do the same thing on a separate PHP page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP [HTTP is intergrated as a so called stream wrapper<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php). That means you can use it with standard file- and stream-related functions:

```
$url = 'http://api.test.com/import-lead-data.php';
$result = file_get_contents($url);
```

This would create a standard GET request. But you want to have a POST request, therefore you need to add some [context options<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php):

```
$url = 'http://api.test.com/import-lead-data.php';
$options['http'] = array(
    'method' => "POST", 
);    
$context = stream_context_create($options);    
$result = file_get_contents($url, NULL, $context);
```

This would make the POST request instead of GET. What's still missing are the form fields. Let's say you have all fields in an array of key => value pairs:

```
$url = 'http://api.test.com/import-lead-data.php';
$content = http_build_query($form_fields);    
$options['http'] = array(
    'method' => "POST", 
    'content' => $content,
);    
$context = stream_context_create($options);    
$result = file_get_contents($url, NULL, $context);
```

Hope that's helpful. Naturally you can use as well the `http_post_data` or `http_post_fields` function as well if you have it available.

See as well: [HEAD first with PHP Streams](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/head-first-with-php-streams/).

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP PECL extension (which contains the HTTPRequest class) isn't part of a default PHP installation.

I would take a look at CURL: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php. You can set the HTTP method and parameters.

Or, if you don't mind using a framework, checkout the Zend FW HTTP Client module: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.html

Here's an example of using CURL to do a post request: http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl

Comment: What about using an http_post_data?

Comment: That's part of the PECL extension. If you are working in an environment that allows you to install PECL modules, then go for it! I tend to avoid this when possible because it makes the code less portable.

Comment: What would the http_post_data syntax look like?

Comment: $data = http_build_query($associativeArrayContainingData);
http_post_data($url, $data);