# PHP get http header response code without cURL

Tags: php, curl, http-headers

I have written a class that detects if cURL is available, if it is performs GET, POST, DELETE using cURL.    In the cURL version I use `curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);` to get the HTTP code.  If is cURL is not available it uses fopen() to read the file contents.  How do I get the HTTP header code without cURL?

Comment: If you are reading the HTTP response stream directly then you have to parse out the headers and response code.  Not a big deal you should be able to find sample code with a quick search.

Comment: I've posted some example code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7566440/367456). A more general description how you can do HTTP with PHP w/o the curl functions is outlined [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9705711/367456).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whenever you do some HTTP interaction, the special variable [`$http_response_header`](http://php.net/http_response_header) on the same scope will contain all headers (incl. the status line header) that are resulted from the last HTTP interaction.

See [here for an example how to parse it and obtain the status code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7566440/367456).

Answer (score 15):

Use [get_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php):

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.example.com/";

$headers = get_headers($url);

$code = $headers[0];
?>
```

**Edit:** `get_headers` requires an additional call, and is not appropriate for this scenario. Use `$http_response_headers` as [suggested by hakre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9725206/302939).

Comment: That will run a request on it's own.

Comment: Ah, you would be correct. My answer is likely not the best option in this case.

Comment: Well technically it's not wrong, because the TS has not posted much code, so it's actually not clear what exactly she/he wanted to know ;)