# How to fill a remote ColdFusion form using PHP?

Tags: php, forms, coldfusion, remote-server

How to fill a remote ColdFusion form and submit it using PHP running on my server? I want to fill a search form on a remote website, which I don't have access to and which is written in ColdFusion, with the data given on my PHP website. I tried PHP cURL, but that didn't work. Don't know whether it is our problem or not.

www.arello.com I want to fill the form on right side of that website. What I get on my php website is users License number. So I want to submit that query to the form and arello.com which is on Coldfusion and submit it to verify the license details. Is there anyway, I can verify using that site with details from my site?

Comment: Share with us what you tried and we can tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: If I understand your question, all you need to do is submit your data to the same page the ColdFusion form is submitting (with all of the required form fields).

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you can't.  If the coldfusion form is not programmed to populate the "value" attribute of each text field with your form/url parameters, then there is nothing you can do with it.

Comment: I believe the php version of cfhttp is cURL which looks like a 3rd party library hacked into php. http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: have you tried doing this instead of curl? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703879/a-cfhttp-post-in-php Just to be clear, you can't populate the actual form to be submitted unless the form was written that way.  but you should be able to submit the same form fields or querystring to the form handler like @Miguel-F said.

Comment: Simply submitting the form may or may not succeed.  If the CF action page is checking the cgi.http_referrer, things won't go as well as the OP had hoped.

Comment: @MattBusche maybe its my fault for interpretting a bad question, but he seems like he is a PHP guy from his server, trying to send variables to a CFM file on another server that he DOES NOT have control of, and then have that FORM post somewhere.  If the CFM which he has no access to doesnt account for the variables being passed over... then there is nothing he could do.

Comment: @DanBracuk http_referrer is about the worst way to test a form, period. It can usually be spoofed. I've even overcome the problem by submitting the request multiple times.  Here's Ben's take on spoofing.  http://www.bennadel.com/blog/903-Passing-Referer-AS-ColdFusion-CFHttp-CGI-Value-vs-HEADER-Value-.htm

Comment: I have edited the question with some more details about the website. Is there any way to do what I said with the website arello.com?

Comment: Not sure why this was closed. It seems like a reasonable question. People have solicited clarification, so why don't we wait for clarification?

Comment: @Travis - Yes `http_referrer` is easily spoofable. But that site *is* using it to prevent access when its disabled. user1954365 - Their [terms of use](https://www.arello.com/index.cfm/legal-info/) state that the site *"uses robot exclusion methods that expressly allow and/or exclude specified automated programs from accessing certain portions of the Website"*. So the errors you are getting are most likely by design. You should contact them about gaining programmatic access. (Their home page says they offer a web service BTW).

Answer (score 3):

It does not really have anything to do with ColdFusion per se. Like a lot of sites, they restrict or prohibit automated access. Their [terms of use](https://www.arello.com/index.cfm/legal-info/) state that:

> "... [this site] uses robot exclusion methods that expressly allow
>   and/or exclude specified automated programs from accessing certain
>   portions of the Website".

One of the methods they are using is to inspect the [http referrer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) value of incoming requests. If that header is missing or empty, they block access. Most likely that is why your `cURL` request fails. It is being blocked by design. You should contact them and ask about gaining programmatic access. Their home page says they offer a "License Verification Web Service":

> "...This new service will allow organizations to connect to ARELLO's
>   database and .. verify licenses in mass numbers. Contact
>   ARELLO for more information ..."